# Typescript readonly everywhere toggle? (function parameters)

Tags: typescript, macros, immutability, readonly

Is there any way, with a macro library, an eslint rule, a tsconfig setting, a magic `global.d.ts` file, or otherwise, to make function arguments readonly by default?

```
// I want the compiler to turn this:
function foo(a: A[], b: Record<string, string> {
}
// Into this
function foo(a: ReadonlyArray<A>, b: Readonly<Record<string, string>> ) {
}
```

Comment: You want something that transforms your code into [invalid TypeScript](https://tsplay.dev/Nlpn5N) automatically?  There's no way to say `readonly b: number` as a function parameter.  What do you mean by that?  That nobody should be allowed to reassign a value to the `b` variable inside the function body?  If so, there's no facility for that, and `ReadonlyArray<A>` doesn't do that for `a` either.  I'm confused; help!

Comment: Maybe you're looking for https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign ?  But that's not achievable by any TS syntax.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the `number` case. Was thinking only of mutable arguments. When I started writing the question I had `foo(args: {a: number, b: string})`. That eslint rule seems useful to but my Q is about having functions not mutate mutable parameters.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-functional

Comment: You want something that transforms a `Record<string, string>`into a `ReadonlyMap<string, string>`? Those are different data structures entirely. Should the transformation also modify property accesses so that something like `b.bar` turns into `b.get("bar")`?  Could you triple check what you're asking for and make sure that the code in your question constitutes a [mre]?

Comment: Fixed another typo, apologies. That eslint plugin looks pretty good, too. Restating my goal/question: Disable or lint-out all mutation on all function parameters. (Don't care about reassigning when primitives are passed)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) ESLint rule:

> This rule aims to prevent unintended behavior caused by modification or reassignment of function parameters.

However this is not a replacement for `readonly`:

```
/* eslint no-param-reassign: ["error", { "props": true, "ignorePropertyModificationsForRegex": ["^mut"] }] */
function f(n: number, nums: number[], o: { p: string }, mutArr: number[]) {
    n = 10 // error
    n++ // error
    for (n in nums) { } // error
    nums[1] = 10 // error
    nums.push(1) // passes
    nums.sort() // passes
    o.p = 'foo' // error
    mutArr[0] = 10 // passes
}
```

Comment: This is great it also works for object/array properties. Main thing it's missing is array methods. Thanks a lot, I'll update the example.

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning that Luke. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open feature request being actively discussed in the typescript github repo for exactly this feature:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42357

It looks like the question of how to deal with untyped library code complicates the feature, so it could be a while before they decide whether or not to add it.